# Magento 2 custom theme doesn't work on "home"

Tags: magento2

I have started to write a custom theme for Magento 2 on basis of the luma theme. I am now facing the problem, that my custom theme applies to all pages BUT the "home" page. The Luma theme is still active there and is not overwritten by my custom theme.

I set the custom theme as default theme and it is applied on every store / view

I have no idea what to do. Does anyone have a solution or faced the same problem?

This is my default.xml:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="logo">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="logo_file" xsi:type="string">images/unfair-athl-black.png</argument>
                <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">200</argument> 
                <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">100</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="copyright" remove="true" />

    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if config is overriding your theme.

1. Check if your Home / Start Page has a Design Update at the bottom of the config page in Content -> Pages -> YourHomePage. (for all Store Views)
2. Check if your Home / Start Page has a layout that is represented in your theme (1 column, 2 column, etc.) (for all Store Views)
3. Manually remove all generated and static content via command `rm -rf magentoroot/var/cache/* magentoroot/var/page_cache/* magentoroot/var/view_preprocessed/* magentoroot/generated/* magentoroot/pub/static/*`
   and re-deploy after
4. Make sure you include `default_head_blocks.xml` in the `default.xml` of your theme

Comment: Checked all of it and everything is just fine, but all the system pages like "home", "no-route", "enable-cookies" etc don't show my theme. Default.xml updated in post above

Comment: Try explicitly assigning your Theme via Design Update. Don't enter a timespan, or layout, just choose your Theme and see if that changes anything. If it does not, there is a problem with your Theme. If it does, there is a problem with your default values.